# md5sum only new files?

Tags: script, checksum

I have a directory containing files and an md5sum.txt file.
I add a file new files to the directory.
I would like add md5sum sums for all files that are not in md5sum.txt.

Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: What kind of script are you looking for? What operating system are you using?

Comment: you basically have to script reading in your md5sum.txt and directory listing and weed out from there.  i'd probably choose perl for the task.

Comment: I'm using Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this little number:

```
#We want the seperator to be newlines, not spaces
IFS="$(echo -e "\n\r")"
for EACHFILE in `ls -1`
do
    # If grep can't find the filename in that text file
    if ! egrep -q  " $EACHFILE$" md5sum.txt; then
    md5sum $EACHFILE
    fi
done
```

This assumes that the text file is like this:

964e6b94e921b5f0879b41956b787050  test.file

Which is standard output

Comment: In OSX I had to change the second line to: `IFS=$'\n'`